# jQuery + AJAX + Cross Domain + Get Content

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, cross-domain, jsonp

I am not sure if its even possible, but I would guess there must be a way.

I am trying to check if a certain page is still online and if it still has the content I expect. For demo purpose I was trying to get the remote site's title.

So I was trying something like this:

```
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp_callback',
    url: 'http://www.confickerworkinggroup.org/infection_test/cfeyechart.html',
    success: function (response) {
      var newTitle = $(response).filter('title').text();
      alert(newTitle);
    }
  });
```

But it doesnt work and this is the error in Firebug:

```
invalid XML attribute value
<META NAME=AUTHOR CONTENT="Joe Stewart">
```

I am new to all of this, so I am not sure where the main problem is (I guess there are more than just one).

Edit:

I think what I actually need help with it, is to "parse" the returned jsonp, so that I can use it with jquery just if it was some simple content.

Edit 2:

Just in case any1 is looking for a similar thing, I came across [this site](http://www.ajax-cross-domain.com/) and it work very nice, however I am still looking for a way to do it with jQuery and will keep this post updated.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like it's working, but it's not returning valid XML in that page because the meta tag has no closing element.  You might want to set the datatype to html instead.

Comment: Hi, yeah also thought it seems to be working, but cant get around that error.... When changing datatype to html, it doesnt work at all. I get "GET http://www.confickerworkinggroup.org/infection_test/cfeyechart.html 200 OK" - but with an empty answer.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a sample that may help you for working with jquery ajax.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "[POST|GET]",
  url: "[URL]",
  data: "{'[key]': '[value]' }",
  contentType: "[Content Type] ",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
    //TODO: Add function or method to response handler
  },
 error: function(e){
  //TODO: Add function or method to error handler.
 }
});
```

type: Type of request do you make.
url: URL you want make a request.
data: JSON data do you want to send (this is a parameters). [Optional]
contentType: Type of content that you are sending. [Optional]
dataType: Data type returned on the response.
success: For add a response handler.
error: For add a error handler.

For more information about $.ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Hi, I would rather need help for my specific question. I can and of course did read the official documentation myself. Thanks!